# CSS - How to align photos to scroll across a page with a hover feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to align multiple images across the page with a horizontal flow scrollbar. I also want each image to have have a separate hover image. I can get one or the other but not both together. I am sure it is an easy process but I am new to HTML/CSS.

Here is what I have with hover but without horizontal scrollbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <img src="lb.jpg" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
   <img src="bungalow.jpg" alt."">
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="lb2.jpg" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
   <img src="bungalow2.jpg" alt."">
</div>
</div>

 <div class="container">
  <img src="lb3.jpg" alt="" class="image" style="width:100%">
   <div class="middle">
   <img src="bungalow3.jpg" alt."">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I have with horizontal scrollbar but without hover:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.slide-container {
  overflow: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }

</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="slide-container">
  <img id="slideone" src="lb.jpg" />
  <img id="slidetwo" src="lb2.jpg" />
  <img id="slidethree" src="lb3.jpg" />
  <img id="slidefour" src="lb4.jpg" />
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to combine the two!

Comment: are you looking for all the images to align horizontally with a scroll-bar?. If yes you need to create a wrapper with fixed widthand overflow-x: auto

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for all the images to align horizontally with a scroll-bar?. If yes you need to create a wrapper with fixed width and overflow-x: auto

```
.parent-container {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow: auto;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            margin: 0 auto;
            white-space: nowrap
}
```

https://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/ybmrNP

Comment: Do you know why this would work perfect in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari?

Also, do you know how to make it scalable to mobile?

Comment: you have to set max-width:100% to .parent-container in a media query. you will see one item visible and you have to scroll to the next items to see the other items. I think you can use a carousel instead of doing like this in actual page. That will be lot user friendly. try slick carousel its very easy

Comment: @KaylaC. I dont have access to safari now. I can check it tomorrow

Comment: I do really like slick carousel. Do you know if I can add that same hover effect using it? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Yes. you can because your hover feature is a css transition. you just need to make sure that both the images are aligned properly within the slick item, then you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to have a div as a container and one div as a parent for each two images, and give them proper position. I make an example for you, hopefully this is what you are looking for :

**UPDATED**

HTML :

```
<div class="imgHolder">
  <div class="parentImage">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" alt="" class="image1"/>  
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2" alt="" class="image2"/>
</div>

<div class="parentImage">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3" alt="" class="image1"/>  
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/1" alt="" class="image2"/>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.imgHolder{
      overflow:scroll;
      height:230px;
      width:400px;
       display:inline-flex;
}

.imgHolder img {
     width:400px;
     height:200px;
 }
.parentImage{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parentImage > .image1{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parentImage > .image2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity:0;
  padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;

  width:95%;
}

.parentImage:hover > .image1{
   opacity:0.3;
}

.parentImage:hover > .image2{
   opacity:1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/f9xd75uv/2/

Comment: I tried this and the hover image worked but I could only scroll vertically. I tried overflow-x but that didn't work either. I updated my original question to include the code I used for the horizontal scroll bar that I want to use.